# Need to convert .mp4 videos to .flv or .fv4

Tags: flash, video, flv, mp4

I have Adobe Flash CS5 but haven't a clue how to convert videos. I also got out my install disks and added Adobe After Effects with Media Encoder as well. Though I thought there would be a standalone Media Encoder app... I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is supposed to be a separate "Adobe Media Encoder" application, that is normally distributed along with the "Creative Suite", for converting videos.

Also, as a side note, if your .mp4 files use the H.264 video codec and AAC audio codec, they can be played in Flash without converting to .flv, so you could check that out first.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html) ([windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) on a separate site).